# Fill 2D array in alternate squares

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

You have a value n, it will determine the dimension of a 2D array or table. Then you should fill the array or the table from the outer layer to the center once with ones and once with zeros up to the point where there is no other element to write.

n=5
  [image: n=5]

n=6
  [image: n=6]

Have been trying this for a long time now, would appreciate any help. Am able to fill the boundaries nothing more.

My latest code :

```
function fillArray(n) {
    var exArray = [];
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        html+= '<tr>';
        exArray[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            exArray[i][j] = 0;
            if(i%(n-1)==0 || j%(n-1)==0) {
                exArray[i][j] = 1;
            }
            html+='<td class="text-center">'+exArray[i][j]+' ['+i+','+j+']</td>';
        };
        html+= '</tr>';
    };
    return html;
}
```

Comment: please post some code that doesn't work

Comment: Seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/h6e9w1fx/ ... otherwise explanation of expected results needs more clarification

Comment: as seen in the ref tables, it needs to keep filling alternate squares until reaches center.

Comment: would only ever be perfect on odd number of `n` ... what is supposed to be done on even `n`?

Comment: You can see it in the ref diag. n=6, center 4 cells get 1. Each alternate squares are to be filled by 1, until you reach center.

Comment: I think I'm close... give me a few more minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the simplest way is considering only the top-left quadrant, and fill the others by symmetry:

```js
var arr = Array(n);
for(var i=0; i<n/2; ++i) {
    arr[  i  ] = new Array(n);
    arr[n-1-i] = new Array(n);
    for(var j=0; j<n/2; ++j)
        arr[  i  ][j] = arr[  i  ][n-1-j] =
        arr[n-1-i][j] = arr[n-1-i][n-1-j] =
        + !(Math.min(i,j) % 2);
}
```

```js
function fillArray(n) {
  var arr = Array(n);
  for(var i=0; i<n/2; ++i) {
    arr[  i  ] = new Array(n);
    arr[n-1-i] = new Array(n);
    for(var j=0; j<n/2; ++j)
      arr[  i  ][j] = arr[  i  ][n-1-j] =
      arr[n-1-i][j] = arr[n-1-i][n-1-j] =
      + !(Math.min(i,j) % 2);
  }
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  for(var i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    var row = table.insertRow();
    for(var j=0; j<n; ++j)
      row.insertCell().textContent = arr[i][j];
  }
  return table;
}
document.body.appendChild(fillArray(9));
```

```css
td {
  width: .8em;
  height: .8em;
  line-height: .8em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as succinct but works:

```
var n = 10;

function isMiddleIndex(middleIdx, rowIndex, cellIndex) {
    return middleIdx.indexOf(rowIndex) != -1 && middleIdx.indexOf(cellIndex) != -1;
}

function isBoundaryIndex(n, boundsIdx, i, j) {
    return boundsIdx.indexOf(i) > -1 || boundsIdx.indexOf(j) > -1;
}

function fillArray(n) {
    var num,
        html = '',
        nMid = n / 2,
        middleIdx = n % 2 == 1 ? [(n - 1) / 2] : [Math.floor(nMid) - 1, Math.ceil(nMid)],
        boundsIdx = [0, n - 1];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        html += '<tr>';
        for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            num = isMiddleIndex(middleIdx, i, j) || isBoundaryIndex(n, boundsIdx, i, j) ? 1 : 0;
            html += '<td class="text-center">' + num + '</td>';
        };
        html += '</tr>';
    };
    return html;
}

$('table').html(fillArray(n));
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vveq65x6/)**</kbd>

Comment: think I misinterpreted expected results on larger tables ... was going on premise only outer and inner got zeros

Answer (score 0):

A more readable way

```
    function fillArray(n) {
    var exArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        exArray[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            exArray[i][j] = 0;
            if(i < j) {
                if(n - j - 1 > i) {
                    if(i % 2 == 0) {
                        exArray[i][j] = 1;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if((n - j - 1) % 2 == 0) {
                        exArray[i][j] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                if(j > n - i - 1) {
                    if((n - i - 1) % 2 == 0) {
                        exArray[i][j] = 1;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if(j % 2 == 0) {
                        exArray[i][j] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    };
}
```

And [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/20tdLvqz/).